# Selenium server start within .NET

Tags: c#, .net, selenium

I'm using Selenium to control Opera within C#. I'm using selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0 .
When i start the server from command line there is no problem . My code work well.
But I need to start the server from C# and I can start it with a bat file execution. I can start the server and create a driver. 
(I'm using `"java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar -trustAllSSLCertificates"` command to start the server in both cases.)

My problem is:

If the server started from C# code, my code can't find the element and throwing exception: (Driver's page source property contains xxx element.)

My Code which throws the exception:
`element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("xxx"));`

All properties of the element throw an exception.

I think it's because of the process.start privileges when i start server. I've searched a lot but i couldn't find anything.

Thanks

Comment: Well what page is this running against? Is this reproducible on another machine? When launched using the bat file, do you see the server startup fine? What code are you using?

Comment: I can start sever with this command "java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar -trustAllSSLCertificates" from command line and C# code.

Answer (score 0):

I can start sever with this command "java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar -trustAllSSLCertificates" from command line and C# code. Server starting well i can create driver and can see the page source .

```
IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new System.Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.Opera());
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100));
```

But when i want to reach WebElement through this code element throws lots of exception ('element.Displayed' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException')

```
IWebElement element; // FindElement(driver, "txtUserName", 100);
element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtUserName"));
string name = element.GetAttribute("Name");
```